# scikit-learn AdaBoostRegressor IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, debugging, scikit-learn

This is the python code that I'm trying to run.

```python
from numpy import *
import pylab as pl
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor

boston = datasets.load_boston()
X, y = shuffle(boston.data, boston.target)
offset = int(0.7*len(X))
X_train, y_train = X[:offset], y[:offset]
X_test, y_test = X[offset:], y[offset:]

regressor = AdaBoostRegressor(n_estimators=5)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

x = [11.95, 0.00, 18.100, 0, 0.6590, 5.6090, 90.00, 1.385, 24, 680.0, 20.20, 332.09, 12.13]
y = regressor.predict(x)
print "Prediction for " + str(x) + " = " + str(y)
```

This is the error I get.

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bug.py", line 18, in <module>
    y = regressor.predict(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 1075, in predict
    return self._get_median_predict(X, len(self.estimators_))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 1050, in _get_median_predict
    median_estimators = sorted_idx[np.arange(X.shape[0]), median_idx]
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I can change the regression function to KNeighborsRegressor or DecisionTreeRegressor and they give me a prediction just fine.

I'm not sure what to do in order to fix this.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

The predict method of regressor is expecting an array of feature vectors. Change:

```
x = [11.95, 0.00, 18.100, 0, 0.6590, 5.6090, 90.00, 1.385, 24, 680.0, 20.20, 332.09, 12.13]
```

to:

```
x = [[11.95, 0.00, 18.100, 0, 0.6590, 5.6090, 90.00, 1.385, 24, 680.0, 20.20, 332.09, 12.13]]
```

then the code will return the prediction for this one feature vector.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the classes were not defined and I wanted to plot the roc_curve using metrics.plot_roc_curve(model,X_test,y_test). Thus I ran into the same error. I solved it by defining the classes.

So if model is your classifier e.g.

```
model = XGBClassifier(...)
```

you can set

```
model.classes_ = np.array([0,1])
```

if you do a binary classifcation.